# Surface area of normal composed with parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry

I wonder if someone can help me with the following problem:

Let M be an oriented regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Gauss map: $N: M \to S^2$ (the unit sphere). Let $X: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to M$ be a local parametrization and let $ A( N \circ X) $ denote the area of the the image of $N \circ X$ on $S^2$. Prove that: $A(N \circ X) = \int_{X(U)} |K| dA$ where K is the Gaissian curvature of M.

I know that the definition of the area is given by $A(X(U))=\int_U \sqrt{EG-F^2}dudv$, and I thought one might apply it to $N \circ X$ but I dont know how the chain rule works in this case. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a matter of change of variable. Remember that by definition, $K(p)=\det (D_{p} N)$. Then:
$$
A(N \circ X) = \int_{N \circ X(U)} 1 \, \mathrm{d} \mathrm{vol}_{S^2} = \int_{X(U)} 1 (N(p)) |\det D_{p}N|\mathrm{d} \mathrm{vol}_{M}(p).
$$